# How to get text before and after specific string

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have content stored in variables and I have a string that users enter in search fields.

My question is how can I chop the text before and after the searched string?

-`SearchString` has a the value which user has entered.

-`Wholetext` has the whole data from database.

Now, I want to show the `Wholetext` as the excerpt like user search for "test" and then I will show the result like:

"text before search string" : "test"

"text after search string" : "**_**"

Here's my code:

```
{% block field %}
    <div>
        {% set SearchString=admin.datagrid.filters.data.value.value %}
        <div class="less_resume_container">
            {% if SearchString is defined and  SearchString in object.data %}
                {% set Wholetext=  object.data|replace({ (SearchString): '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold">' ~SearchString~'</span>'}) %}
                {{ Wholetext|striptags()|truncate(50) }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show_full_resume">Show
                more</a>
            {% else %}
                {% set  Wholetext=  object.data %}
                {{ Wholetext|truncate(50) }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show_full_resume">Show more</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="full_resume_container" style="display: none;">{{ Wholetext|raw() }}
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show_less_resume">View less</a>
        </div>

        <br/>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Currently it is showing 50 characters from the text.
This is not what I want. By the way I am using sonata admin with symfony 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of substr and strlen.

```
substr(WHOLETEXT, 0, (strlen(WHOLETEXT) - strlen(SEARCHTERM)))
```

Alternatively, you could explode the whole text on the search term, which would leave you with a two part array(assuming your search term only appeared once). The first part would be everything before the search term. The second part would be everything after.

```
$array = explode(SEARCHTERM, WHOLETEXT); 
$before = $array[0];
$after = $array[1];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how can i implement this in twig ? any idea